# How can I use GPU in Docker image with Theano launched from Windows host?

Tags: windows, docker, theano-cuda

I want to run Theano via Docker image on my PC with Windows installed.
The Docker image contains Ubuntu system, CUDA drivers and Theano (https://hub.docker.com/r/kaixhin/cuda-theano/) but in order to use GPU in my algorithm I need to attach Nvidia devices to the image:

`docker run -it --device /dev/nvidiactl --device /dev/nvidia-uvm --device /dev/nvidia0 kaixhin/cuda-theano`

Is there a way to do it in Windows, since I don't have a path `/dev/nvidiactl` etc.? I have been looking for other [Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=2&pullCount=0&q=cuda%20theano&starCount=0) but it seems that all of these are using Linux as the host system. Is there a version that will allow me to use GPU from Windows?

For now I can run my script in Docker, but it uses only my CPU:

`WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu is not available  (error: Unable to get the number of gpus available: no CUDA-capable device is detected)`

Answer (score 1):

In order to run CUDA Docker images you need [NVIDIA Docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker).   Unfortunately, Theano is not supported as an official image at the moment but you can write your own Dockerfile leveraging [nvidia/cuda](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/)

Having said that, you won't be able to do it on Windows because Docker needs a Linux VM and there is no support for VM GPU passthrough on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this image:

https://hub.docker.com/r/kaixhin/cuda-theano/

It requires `nvidia-docker`

`nvidia-docker run -it kaixhin/cuda-theano`